# How to print last directory inside every parent directory

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix

I have set of directories and sub-directories as below.

```
aaa/180809_1047
aaa/180915_0055
aaa/181012_1545
aaa/xyz
bbb/180809_1047
bbb/180915_0055
bbb/181012_1545
bbb/181105_0000
bbb/xyz
.
.
.
zzz/180821_1555
zzz/181004_2355
zzz/xyz
```

Most of the sub-directories are in YYMMDD_HHMM format. Here I'm trying to print the sub-directories which are in the format YYMMDD_HHMM only (latest) from every parent directory. Below is my requirement.

output:

```
aaa/181012_1545
bbb/181105_0000
zzz/181004_2355
```

I have used find command as below:

```
find ./*/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "???????????" | sort -u | tail -1
```

`"???????????"` --> this is to print the directories that matches the format YYMMDD_HHMM.

After this command I'm getting only.

```
zzz/181004_2355
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this natively in bash using a `for` loop, rather than using `find`.

I honestly can't remember if bash makes any promises about the order in which globs will be processed. So, using the sample date you included, here's a one-liner that compares files using `[[`:

```
$ declare -A last=(); for a in *; do for b in $a/[0-9]*/; do [[ $b > $last[$a] ]] && last[$a]=$b; done; done; declare -p last
declare -A last=([bbb]="bbb/181105_0000/" [zzz]="zzz/181004_2355/" [aaa]="aaa/181012_1545/" )
```

Note that the limiting patern here is `$a/[0-9]*/`, which is sufficient for your sample data. You can of course restrict this as necessary, using character classes and eliminating the glob.

Note also that the trailing `/` in this pattern ensures that you will only match things that are directories. This will put a `/` at the end of every result in the `$last` array. You can post-process if required:

```
$ for i in "${!last[@]}"; do last[$i]="${last[$i]%/}"; last[$i]="${last[$i]#*/}"; done
$ declare -p last
declare -A last=([bbb]="181105_0000" [zzz]="181004_2355" [aaa]="181012_1545" )
```

For easier reading, here's the one-liner split into multiple lines. :)

```
# Create an associative array. Requires bash 4+.
declare -A last=()

# Step through the top-level directories
for a in *; do
  # Step through the second level directories
  for b in "$a"/[0-9]*/; do
    # Compare and record as required
    [[ $b > $last[$a] ]] && last[$a]="$b"
  done
done

# Print the result
declare -p last
```

Comment: Native glob sort depends on LOCALE environment settings, LC_ALL overrides. So it is one of those -- it depends things...

Answer (score 0):

You're tailing the output of the command with `tail -1`. So you will only get the very last line. :)

Beyond that your command looks correct.

Couple other notes:

1. You can write `find .` without the glob because find is recursive by default
2. `???????????` could be more restrictive if you needed. `??????_????` or using `[[:digit:]]` would be options.

Comment: My intension to get last line bez i have used sort to get the latest subdirectory at the end. since **tail -1** only gets me the last line of all print ( in this case its zzz/181004_2355), what can be done to get all the latest sub-directories like below?.<br/>                                                                                           aaa/181012_1545<br/>
bbb/181105_0000<br/>
zzz/181004_2355<br/>

Answer (score 0):

The idea to use `sort -u` and `tail -1` is good, and it'll work when used with the list of sub directories from within the same parent directory. The `-u` is going to remove duplicates, but this is not needed because 2 sub directories cannot have the same name within the same parent directory.

`?` means any chars; a more restrictive `[0-9]` can be used instead to select a single digit.

Give a try to this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
 for dir ; do 
   find "${dir}" -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -name '[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9]' | sort | tail -1
 done' dummy | sort
```

For each directory found at the first level (first `find . -maxdepth 1 ...`):

- all sub directories that match the pattern
  `[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9]` are listed (second `find`)
- only the latest is printed (thanks to `sort` and
  `tail` commands)

the `-print0` and `-0` arguments are used together with the `sh -c` and the `for statement` to make the command line robust to filenames with special chars, such as `line break`.

`dummy` is not used but it is mandatory, see `man sh`

**TEST**

```
mkdir -p aaa/180809_1047 aaa/180915_0055 aaa/181012_1545 aaa/xyz \
bbb/xyz bbb/180809_1047 bbb/180915_0055 bbb/181012_1545 bbb/181105_0000 \
zzz/xyz zzz/180821_1555 zzz/181004_2355

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
  for dir ; do 
    find "${dir}" -maxdepth 1 -type d \
     -name '[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9]' | sort | tail -1
  done' dummy | sort


./bbb/181105_0000
./aaa/181012_1545
./zzz/181004_2355
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find, sort, awk:

```
find -name '??????_????' -type d | sort -r | awk -F'/' '{if(!s[$(NF-1)]++) print $0}
```